# My site is based on Symfony 1.4 and often crashes/goes down

Tags: php, symfony1

It works properly, and after some minutes it just goes down... timeout, or no response. After some time it lives again. I don't do any special things, just testing. Has anybody met this situation?

Comment: even the direct link to images doesnt work either!

Comment: Seems like a webserver problem, contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

are you running it locally? if so.. check your apache or IIS or whatever server you're using.

**EDIT**

For it to run local download

[xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Check if you get the same problems

Comment: @JohnSmith that might be your answer :)

Comment: i would say that if it works locally and only on the server... it most likely the free hosting. FTP uses a different port (21) instead of web (80 and 8080) also web server and ftp server.